# JavaScript - Problema con DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi codigo.

Tengo un bloque de código que mediante un querySelectorAll selecciona todos los buttons que posean la id=#delete-button. Hasta acá todo bien, trae todos los botones y les escucha el evento "click" a cada uno. El problema es con el confirm(). Una vez que se aprieta un boton, no importa que le de "Aceptar" o "Cancelar", el popup aparece infinitas veces.

**Les dejo el codigo:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll("#delete-button");
    //listen to click 
    for(let button of deleteBtns){
        button.addEventListener("click" , (e) =>{

            //display confirm popup
            let result = confirm("¿Seguro desea eliminar el producto?");
    
            //confirm
            if(result == true){
                e.submit();
            }
            //cancel
            else{
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias.

Comment: deleteButtons devuelve un array con todos los elementos que poseen dicha id, no funcionaría si no itero sobre este.

Comment: No uses el id, usa un classname: class="name", porque los id se hicieron para que sea único de un objeto y de nadie mas, en cambios las clases se hicieron para que se repita muchas veces y obtener un array de todas las clases es mucho mas facil que obtener un array con el mismo id porque los id no están diseñados para ello

Comment: No entiendo, el código hace lo que debería, Si le das cancelar evita que envíe el formulario, si le das enviar lo envias(Solo te sirve si usas botones y no input type="submit" pero si previene el envio)

Comment: Son etiquetas <button> y no tiene nada que ver lo de que sea id o clase. Si vos utilizas un querySelectorAll tendría que tomarlos todos. De todas formas intente utilizando clase y ocurre lo mismo...

Comment: ... No estoy diciendo que los id o los class tengan algo que ver con esa etiqueta solo digo que tu código solo funciona con botones y no con input del tipo submit y al momento de hacer e.submit() daba el error sobre que esa función no existe, solo está disponible en los <button/> que estan dentro de form

Comment: Y con los id o class, solo es cuestión de estándar. Tu a llamar a: document.getElementById("") solo te retornará un elemento con ese id(Sin importar que haya mas elementos con el mismo id), en cambio si llamas a document.getElementsByClassName("") te retorna una colección de elementos que tengan esa misma clase. Si te funciona querySelectorAll, bien por ti.

Comment: Pero como te digo el código hace lo que debería (Si se presiona aceptar se envía el formulario y vas a otra página, si le das cancelar se detiene el envío)